# In a commutative diagram in Homotopy Type Theory, why the commutativity is expressed as equality between functions and not as a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

I assume that I employ Homotopy Type Theory. Let $f:A\rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow D, h:A\rightarrow C, k: C\rightarrow D$ so that a commutative diagram is formulated. Commutativity is translated as: $g \circ f=k\circ h$ as far as I saw in relevant material. However I would expect that the two compositions are homotopy equivalent, namely, $g \circ f \sim k\circ h$ and due to function extensionality: $(g \circ f \sim k\circ h) \simeq (g \circ f = k\circ h)$.
In addition, if the diagram also expresses a homotopy pullback, the latter will be demonstrated by the latter equation, viz. $(g \circ f \sim k\circ h) \simeq (g \circ f = k\circ h)$.
Where am I wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To express that your square is a homotopy pullback the commutativity of your square will not be enough. In addition you have to prove for any type $X$ an equivalence between  the type $X\rightarrow A$ of maps  from $X$ to $A$ and the type $\displaystyle \sum_{i:X\rightarrow B} \sum_{j:X\rightarrow C} g\circ i = k\circ j$.